# Log4net does not log via remote desktop

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

I have basic console app in C# with log4net for logging. The app is located in another computer. When I connect to the computer via network drive and run the app, it logs normally, but when I connect to the computer via Remote Desktop and run it from there, the app runs but does not log.

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="log\App.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value=" %date %level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Any ideas where is a problem?

Comment: Insufficient permissions? Maybe you're logging through different account?

Comment: Did you check the path/file on the machine you connected to? If you start it from NetShare, it will run on _your_ machine using _your_ (local) FileSystem. If you connect via remote, it will run on the _remote_ machine, using the _remote_ FileSystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in access permissions to the folder.